# Out of memory error on 10-inch tablets only - Android

Tags: android, memory

I am testing an Android game on several devices including smartphones and 7-inch tablets and it crashes with an OOM error on the two 10-inch tablets only.  One is an Acer A500 and the other a Samsung Galaxy Tab2.  The codes and resources are obviously the same.  I have bitmap resources in the mdpi and xhdpi folders only.  After spending a week on this problem I have no idea where to look.

Would anyone have an idea?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Out of memory error \[duplicate\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189561/out-of-memory-error).

Comment: would you please!! post the code where you getting error, I had the same issue earlier and resolved it. Without looking at your code I would say you must leaking memory somewhere, you can check [**MAT**](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2013/11/how-to-check-memory-leaks-using-eclipse.html) also.

Comment: I have no idea what code to post.  I have 15 java files and about the same in XML files.

Comment: The problem always occurs the second time I launch a game from my "levels" screen.  The levels activity is made of three fragments which can be scrolled to view all the levels.  Like I said, I get an OOM error only on my two 10-inch tablets so I am wondering what is going on here. Like some have suggested in similar links, I do not want to support two APK files.  I want only one APK for all devices.

Comment: I have been using MAT with no success so far.  The DDMS error log says that I am getting the OOM error when the app tries to go from the levels activity (three fragments) to the game activity (main game thread).